# I am writing a java program that looks for abbreviations of BFF, IDK, JK, TMI or TTYL and expands them

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am writing a java program that takes a users input and looks for the abbreviations of BFF, IDK, JK, TMI or TTYL. It is supposed to take the user input and expand the abbreviations to what they stand for and replace the abbreviations with the expanded form. I've been using switch statements and have searched all over the place for some answers but nothing seems to fit. This is my first ever question so I'm gonna try to include my code as well.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TextMsgExpander {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = "";

System.out.println("Enter text: ");
userInput = scnr.nextLine();
String userAbv = userInput;

System.out.println("You entered: " + userInput);

switch (userAbv) {
        case "BFF":
            userAbv = userInput.replace("BFF", "best friends forever");
            System.out.println("Replaced 'BFF' with 'best friends 
            forever'");
            break;
        case "IDK":
            userAbv = userInput.replace("IDK", "I don't know");
            System.out.println("Replaced 'IDK' with 'I don't know'");
            break;
        case "JK":
            userAbv = userInput.replace("JK", "just kidding");
            System.out.println("Replaced 'JK' with 'just kidding'");
            break;
        case "TMI":
            userAbv = userInput.replace("TMI", "too much information");
            System.out.println("Replaced 'TMI' with 'too much 
            information'");
            break;
        case "TTYL":
            userAbv = userInput.replace("TTYL", "talk to you later");
            System.out.println("Replaced 'TTYL' with 'talk to you later'");
            break;

        }

            System.out.println("Expanded: " + userAbv);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you included an actual question here...

Comment: @Makoto Sorry I guess my Question is: is there a better way do make this work. If I just type abbreviations it works fine, am I on the right path or not?

Comment: You're going to want to edit that into your question to begin with...but "am I doing this right" is a bit broad of a question.  It doesn't sound like a specific problem, but rather a request for critique on your work.  Chiefly, my advice would be to be content with the easy-to-understand approach, but don't be afraid to experiment with your code.  It doesn't really require a question here unless you're genuinely *stuck* with a problem.

Comment: @Makoto Yes the problem I have is that I am stuck and banging my head against the wall. This code doesn't work and I can't figure out why. If I type for example "We are BFF." I want to get back a line saying "Replaced BFF with best friends forever" and then a line "Expanded : We are best friends forever." but my last line just repeats the original user input of "We are BFF."

Comment: **Be explicit about what doesn't work.** We can't guess at it; all you've given us is your problem description and your code.  Tell us **exactly** what doesn't work **in your question**.  Doesn't matter if it's not giving you the right output, or doesn't compile, you have to be complete in this.  Also, giving us some sample input and a more complete program to run locally for ourselves would benefit the both of us, so we could see what's really going on.

Comment: side note, I think a map will do well here. you can read about them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), especially if you plan to add more and more abbreviations

Answer (score -2):

Here is my proposition. I comment the replacement message.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextMsgExpander {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  String userInput = "";
  System.out.println("Enter text: ");
  userInput = scnr.nextLine();


  String[] userInputArray = userInput.split(" ");



  for(int i=0; i<userInputArray.length; i++){

     String userAbv = userInputArray[i];

     switch (userAbv) {

        case "BFF":
            userAbv = userAbv.replace("BFF", "best friends forever");
            //System.out.println("Replaced 'BFF' with 'best friends forever'");
            break;

        case "IDK":
            userAbv  = userAbv.replace("IDK", "I don't know");
            //System.out.println("Replaced 'IDK' with 'I don't know'");
            break;

        case "JK":
            userAbv  = userAbv.replace("JK", "just kidding");
            //System.out.println("Replaced 'JK' with 'just kidding'");
            break;

        case "TMI":
            userAbv  = userAbv.replace("TMI", "too much information");
            //System.out.println("Replaced 'TMI' with 'too much information'");
            break;

        case "TTYL":
            userAbv  = userAbv.replace("TTYL", "talk to you later");
            //System.out.println("Replaced 'TTYL' with 'talk to you later'");
            break;
    }

    userInputArray[i] = userAbv ;

}

String newUserInput = join(userInputArray);

System.out.println("You entered: " + userInput);
System.out.println("\n");
System.out.println("Expanded: " + newUserInput);

}


public static String join(String[] x){

    String str="";

    for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++){
        str = str + " " + x[i];
    }

    return str.trim();
}
}
```

> **Input:** BFF is well
>   **Output:** best friends forever is well
>
> **Input:** BFF is well IDK
>   **Output:** best friends forever is well I don't know

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I need. I had found some things about split and array but wasn't sure how to use them. I was so stuck it was killing me. Now I just have to do some research so I understand better HOW and Why this works.

Comment: @DanSkender, You should make my "answer useful" and "accept it". Others people can benefit.